# applyLinearImpulse not working (Box2d)?

Tags: java, android, box2d

I am using a `ContactListener` to listen for any contact, and if collision is detected between the ball and ground, the ball should get an impulse in the upward direction, which is provided in the `void endContact()` function of the `ContactListener` class. But this impulse is having no effect at all, for any impulse value. The ball just bounces off the same distance for any impulse value. What am I doing wrong. Here's the full code:

```
public class Game implements ApplicationListener {
     World world ;  
     Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;  
     OrthographicCamera camera;  
     static final float BOX_STEP=1/60f;  
     static final int BOX_VELOCITY_ITERATIONS=8;  
     static final int BOX_POSITION_ITERATIONS=3;  
     static final float WORLD_TO_BOX=0.01f;  
     static final float BOX_WORLD_TO=100f;  
     Rectangle ball;
     Body body;

    @Override  
     public void create() {
          world = new World(new Vector2(0, -100), true);
          camera = new OrthographicCamera(); 

          camera.viewportHeight = 480;  
          camera.viewportWidth = 800;  
          camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth * .5f, camera.viewportHeight * .5f, 0f);  
          camera.update();

          //Ground body  
          BodyDef groundBodyDef =new BodyDef();  
          groundBodyDef.position.set(new Vector2(0, 10));  
          Body groundBody = world.createBody(groundBodyDef);  
          PolygonShape groundBox = new PolygonShape();  
          groundBox.setAsBox((camera.viewportWidth) * 2, 10.0f);  
          groundBody.createFixture(groundBox, 0.0f);  

          //Dynamic Body  
          BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();  
          bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;  
          bodyDef.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 8, camera.viewportHeight / 2);  
          body = world.createBody(bodyDef); 

          // create a Rectangle to logically represent the ball
          CircleShape dynamicCircle = new CircleShape();  
          dynamicCircle.setRadius(40f);  
          FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();  
          fixtureDef.shape = dynamicCircle;  
          fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;  
          fixtureDef.friction = 0.0f;  
          fixtureDef.restitution =1f;
          body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
          debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();  

          listener listener1=new listener();
          world.setContactListener(listener1);
     }
     @Override  
     public void render() {            
          Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);  
          debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);  
          world.step(BOX_STEP, BOX_VELOCITY_ITERATIONS, BOX_POSITION_ITERATIONS);


     }  
     class listener implements ContactListener 
     {

        @Override
        public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void endContact(Contact contact) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            body.applyLinearImpulse(0, 500000f, body.getWorldCenter().x, body.getWorldCenter().y, true);
            //body.setLinearVelocity(0,50000000);
            System.out.println("Collision detected");
        }

        @Override
        public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        } 

     }; 

     @Override  
     public void resize(int width, int height) {  
     }  
     @Override  
     public void pause() {  
     }  
     @Override  
     public void resume() {  
     }  
     @Override  
     public void dispose() {  
     }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original C++ version, EndContact is called inside the Step function, which is a time when you cannot alter anything in the world because the engine is still using it. I would think that the Java version is the same. You will probably need to make a note of the fact that the ball has bounced, and apply the impulse after the Step has finished.

Comment: You mean in the render after the contact? How exactly?

Comment: Yes. You cannot do the apply impulse inside the EndContact, so just set some variable, so that you know you need to do the apply impulse afterwards.

Comment: That changed nothing.. I added a boolean in `endContact()` which set a variable in the `Game` class to true. The render() function checks if that variable is true, if yes it executes this code: `body.applyLinearImpulse(0, 500000f, body.getWorldCenter().x, body.getWorldCenter().y, true);
           contact=false;`. But all this changed nothing. Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Looking at your code a bit more, it is unusual to have a circle as large as 40 radius. Remember that Box2D uses meters, not pixels, so this would be about the size of a ten storey building. There is also a default maximum velocity limit of 2 meters per time  step which you might be coming up against. It's better to keep the size of dynamic bodies to around 1.

Comment: I changed the radius to 1 and the jump height is still the same, is there something wrong with this syntax: `body.applyLinearImpulse(0, 500000f, body.getWorldCenter().x, body.getWorldCenter().y, false);`?

Comment: The resolution in which this runs is 800*480 so the screen is 480 meters high, 2 meters per time step doesn't make sense in such a big space..

Comment: With a time step length of 1/60s, 2 meters per time step is 120m/s or 432 km/h, almost 1.5 times the speed of sound - not fast enough? Looking at your code again I see the gravity is -100, which is about ten times what is typically used. My guess is that when you apply that huge impulse, the speed is being clamped to 2 meters per time step, and then the enormous gravity quickly decays the remaining speed. Check the velocity in the step after applying impulse, if it's around 120 then this is what's happening.

Comment: Yeah you were right, I was hitting the max velocity limit. I changed pixels to meters and it works though there is a new problem, now the ball has some imaginary force in the y direction which increases its height on every bounce, check it out if you want> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20016142/body-moving-without-any-force-applied-box2d

Answer (score 0):

The reason that there is no impact on of impulse is you are try to apply impulse in the endcontact method.

In box2d ContactListener methods you cannot change the property or position of body.

You can do like this

```
boolean b;
 @Override
    public void endContact(Contact contact) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //body.applyLinearImpulse(0, 500000f, body.getWorldCenter().x, body.getWorldCenter().y, true);
        //body.setLinearVelocity(0,50000000);
       b = true;
        System.out.println("Collision detected");
    }
```

In you update method.....

```
if(b)
{
  body.applyLinearImpulse(0, 500000f, body.getWorldCenter().x, body.getWorldCenter().y, true);
}
```